# How write a for loop with ttk combobox

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, ttk

I just want to know howmany items are there in a ttk combobox, this I want to use

to do the For Loop, somebody please tell me how to do this. I am getting error out

of my code, somebody please note my code and help me

```
def WriteComboBoxValues(cls_Obj1): 

    for P in cls_Obj1.boxWidget["Combo1"]:

        txtData=str(cls_Obj1.boxWidget["Combo1"]['values'][P])+"\n" 

    print txtData += "\n"
```

Comment: What error?! At the very least, provide the traceback.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, appriciate for responding, please note the error Exception in Tkinter callback


Traceback (most recent call last):


    for P in cls_Obj1.boxWidget["Combo1"]:
 
  File "C:\Python26\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1206, in cget
  
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'cget', '-' + key)
 
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

Comment: At-least how to know the count of a combo box widget values, say for example if one combo box contains 4 items, how can I write a code statement to get this count. Something like this DataCount=cls_Obj1.boxWidget["Combo1"].count, this should return a value 4, somebody please help me soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
how_many = len(combobox.cget('values'))
```

Comment: appreciate you for helping me, it helped me.